# How to make a method to split two strings in an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to return two strings in an array into individual words:

```
list = ['hello my name is ryan', 'hole me llamo']
def splitter(inp)
  inp.each.split(' ')
end

print splitter(list)
```

This returns:

```
ruby splitter.rb
splitter.rb:4:in `splitter': undefined method `strsplit' for # <Enumerator: ["hello my name is ryan", "hole me llamo"]:each> (NoMethodError)
from splitter.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

It works if I don't use `.each` and use `inp(0)` or `inp(1)` but only one string returns.

How can I get both strings to be returned?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one you should do :

```
def splitter(inp)
  inp.flat_map(&:split)
end
splitter list
# => ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "ryan", "hole", "me", "llamo"]
```

In your code `inp.each` was actually a method call like `Array#each`, which without a *block* gives an `Enumerator`. And `String#spilt` does exist, but there is not method like `Enumerator#split`, that's why **NoMethod** error blows up.

And if you want the array of words for each individual strings, then

```
def splitter(inp)
  inp.map(&:split)
end
splitter list
# => [["hello", "my", "name", "is", "ryan"], ["hole", "me", "llamo"]]
```

Comment: `inp.flat_map(&:split)`

Comment: Hello, Arup. Can't sleep?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes I do.. But I had to read some topics.. That's why late.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it's just:

```
list = ['hello my name is ryan', 'hole me llamo']

list.join(' ').split
  #=> ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "ryan", "hole", "me", "llamo"]
```